# Skype: show previously hidden chat; show text in recent chats

Tags: skype

In the chat window (Skype > Recent Chats) I have the list of contacts and groups that I've been in touch with recently. I have right-clicked on one of the chat groups which wasn't saved to my favourites and chosen 'Hide chat'. Now I cannot access this group from anywhere. Is there a way to show hidden group chats?

Also, it looks like I can't see any text from recent chats I've been to. How do I access chat history? In Options > Privacy I have the option to keep chat history forever selected.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with Skype 4.2.0.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are getting 'chat deprecated' messages in your event history in Skype 4.2, [update to Skype 4.3](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64).**

If you click on the event history button (clock above and to the right of the contact list), you should be able to search through your event history, and reopen the chat through there.

To see more of your chat history, just set the history filter (the clock next to the plus in the chat window) to forever.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. This is actually the history I was looking for. Unfortunately I can't find anything related to the hidden group there. However, I see a bunch of 'this chat is deprecated' links which don't lead to anywhere. These might be related to the hidden chats.

Comment: Sounds like Microsoft is already phasing out the old chat (and hence the old version)... Try downloading the newer version (4.3): http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64

Comment: Awesome! It worked for me in 4.3 :)

Comment: Okay! I'll update my answer.